# Game winning odds.

Tags: probability

There's this game where you can pick 9 from 80 numbers (1-80). Then 20 of those 80 numbers are drawn. To win you need to have the nine numbers you picked appear on the 20 balls that were drawn. Sometimes you are able to have 22 balls drawn.
What is the probability that you win when 20 balls and when 22 balls are drawn.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)?  Compare your scenario to having a bucket with nine red balls and 71 blue balls, drawing a red counts as success., and asking the probability of when drawing $20$ balls without replacement (*or 22 for the other problem*) that you get nine successes and 11 failures (*i.e. 9 red and 11 blue balls drawn*).

Comment: As a nitpick, the word "odds" and "probability" have different mathematical connotations.  The probability of flipping a head on a fair coin is $\frac{1}{2}$.  The *odds* of flipping a head on a fair coin are "$1$ to $1$".

Comment: I have not heard of hypergeometric distribution and I wasn't aware of the differing mathematical connotation between probability and odds.

Comment: Well, the link above should give you more information than you could ever want about hypergeometric distributions., but the short version is to recognize that each of the $\binom{80}{20}$ ways of selecting twenty numbers are (*presumably*) equally likely, and of these $\binom{9}{9}\binom{71}{11}$ of which involve all nine of your selected numbers.  Taking the ratio gives the probability.

Comment: Taking the ratio of what exactly would give me the probability?

Comment: The number of possibilities of number drawings that involve all nine selected numbers compared to the number of number drawings possible in general... $\dfrac{\binom{9}{9}\binom{71}{11}}{\binom{80}{20}}$.  This is all explained in great detail in my original link.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. I think I forgot to add that the same number cannot be drawn twice. I apologize if I didn't make that clear :(.

Comment: That is what "*drawing without replacement*" means... it is already accounted for in the above calculations.  As for the correctness, I can guarantee you that it is.  The problem you describe is an *incredibly* common one, and you should by visiting the link see several examples identical in every way except for flavor and exact numbers used to your own.

Comment: Ok, I understand now thanks!

Comment: You only need to draw 75 of the 80 balls before you have better than even chances of winning:  $$\dfrac{ \dbinom{9}{9}\dbinom{71}{65} }{ \dbinom{80}{74} } < \dfrac{1}{2} < \dfrac{\dbinom{9}{9}\dbinom{71}{66}}{\dbinom{80}{75}}$$